# How do I fix error for 64-bit VBA PPT converted from 32-bit

Tags: vba, powerpoint

This VBA program worked for 32-bit PPT 2007 but when I used it for 64-bit PPT 2013, there was an error even when I added `PtrSafe` infront of `Public Declare`.

There was a type miss match in this function: `AddressOf BrowseCallbackProc`
(in the middle of Public Function `Get_IMGFolderName()`)

I would like some advice on how to solve this problem.
I have been coding as a hobby so I do not know much.

Thankyou

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32" (lpbi As BrowseInfo) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32" (ByVal pidList As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcat Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrcatA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As String) As Long

Public Type BrowseInfo
    hwndOwner       As Long
    pIDLRoot        As Long
    pszDisplayName  As Long
    lpszstrMsg      As Long
    ulFlags         As Long
    lpfnCallback    As Long
    lParam          As Long
    iImage          As Long
End Type

Public Const BIF_STATUSTEXT = &H4&
Public Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = 1
Public Const BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN = 2
Public Const MAX_PATH = 260
Public Const WM_USER = &H400
Public Const BFFM_INITIALIZED = 1
Public Const BFFM_SELCHANGED = 2
Public Const BFFM_SETSTATUSTEXT = (WM_USER + 100)
Public Const BFFM_SETSELECTION = (WM_USER + 102)

Public strCurDir As String   '현재 디렉토리

  Public Enum CHOOSE_COLOR_FLAGS
    CC_RGBINIT = &H1&
    CC_FULLOPEN = &H2&
    CC_PREVENTFULLOPEN = &H4&
    CC_SHOWHELP = &H8&
    CC_ENABLEHOOK = &H10&
    CC_ENABLETEMPLATE = &H20&
    CC_ENABLETEMPLATEHANDLE = &H40&
    CC_SOLIDCOLOR = &H80&
    CC_ANYCOLOR = &H100&
  End Enum

  Private Type CHOOSECOLOR
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As Long
    hInstance As Long
    rgbResult As Long
    lpCustColors As Long
    flags As CHOOSE_COLOR_FLAGS
    lCustData As Long
    lpfnHook As Long
    lpTemplateName As String
  End Type

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function ChooseColor_API Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "ChooseColorA" (lpChoosecolor As CHOOSECOLOR) As Long



Function Delete_Sheets()

'ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
While ActivePresentation.Slides.Count > 0
    ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Delete
Wend

End Function



Public Function Get_IMGFolderName() As String

Dim lpIDList As Long
Dim szstrMsg As String
Dim strBuffer As String
Dim tBrowseInfo As BrowseInfo
Dim strDir As String

strCurDir = frmBible.lblIMGFolder.Caption & vbNullChar

szstrMsg = "바탕그림용 이미지가 들어 있는 폴더를 지정해주세요"
With tBrowseInfo
    .hwndOwner = 0
    .lpszstrMsg = lstrcat(szstrMsg, "")
    .ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS + BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN + BIF_STATUSTEXT
    .lpfnCallback = GetAddressofFunction(AddressOf BrowseCallbackProc)  'get address of function.
End With

lpIDList = SHBrowseForFolder(tBrowseInfo)
If (lpIDList) Then
    strBuffer = Space(MAX_PATH)
    SHGetPathFromIDList lpIDList, strBuffer
    strBuffer = Left(strBuffer, InStr(strBuffer, vbNullChar) - 1)
    Get_IMGFolderName = strBuffer
Else
    Get_IMGFolderName = ""
End If

End Function



Public Function Remove_Special_Chars(intxt) As String

Dim wkstr As String
Dim p As Integer, c, uc

wkstr = ""
While Len(intxt) > 0
    c = Left(intxt, 1)
    uc = UCase(c)
    If c >= "가" And c <= "힝" Then
        wkstr = wkstr & c
    ElseIf uc >= "A" And uc <= "Z" Then
        wkstr = wkstr & c
    ElseIf uc >= "0" And uc <= "9" Then
        wkstr = wkstr & c
    End If
    intxt = Mid(intxt, 2)
Wend

Remove_Special_Chars = wkstr

End Function




Public Function Return_PathName(full_Path As String)

'return path name only

Dim p As Integer, ps As Integer

ps = 1
p = 1
Do While p > 0
    p = InStr(ps, full_Path, "\", vbBinaryCompare)
    If p > 0 Then
        ps = p + 1
    End If
Loop

Return_PathName = Left(full_Path, ps - 1)

End Function

Public Function Return_FileName(full_Path As String)

' return file name only

Dim p As Integer, ps As Integer

ps = 1
p = 1
Do While p > 0
    p = InStr(ps, full_Path, "\", vbBinaryCompare)
    If p > 0 Then
        ps = p + 1
    End If
Loop

Return_FileName = Mid(full_Path, ps)

End Function

Public Function Return_FolderName(full_Path)

' return folder name only

Dim p As Integer

p = InStrRev(full_Path, "\", Len(full_Path) - 1)

Return_FolderName = Mid(full_Path, p + 1)

End Function





Public Function BrowseCallbackProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal lp As Long, ByVal pData As Long) As Long
Dim lpIDList As Long
Dim lngRet As Long
Dim strBuffer As String

On Error Resume Next

Select Case uMsg

    Case BFFM_INITIALIZED
        Call SendMessage(hWnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, 1, strCurDir)

    Case BFFM_SELCHANGED
        strBuffer = Space(MAX_PATH)

        lngRet = SHGetPathFromIDList(lp, strBuffer)
    If lngRet = 1 Then
        Call SendMessage(hWnd, BFFM_SETSTATUSTEXT, 0, strBuffer)
    End If

End Select
On Error GoTo 0

BrowseCallbackProc = 0

End Function



Public Function GetAddressofFunction(lngAdd As Long) As Long

GetAddressofFunction = lngAdd

End Function


Public Function FileDateInfo(filespec)
    Dim fs, f
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(filespec)
    FileDateInfo = f.DateLastModified

End Function


Public Function WinRegistry_CommonGet()

Dim TmpName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim x

Version_Release = GetSetting("BibleChoir", "LatestVal", "Version_Release", "vv.rr")


frmBible.lblIMGFolder.Caption = GetSetting("BibleChoir", "LatestVal", "IMGFolder", "없음")
'frmPicture.sldBright = GetSetting(appname:="BibleChoir", section:="LatestVal", key:="Bright", Default:=70)
frmBible.chkEachPage = GetSetting("BibleChoir", "LatestVal", "EachPage", False)

 File2Open = frmBible.lblIMGFolder.Caption


 If File2Open <> "없음" Then
  On Error Resume Next
 frmBible.ImgPreview.Picture = LoadPicture(File2Open)
 End If
 On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function WinRegistry_CommonSave()

Dim i As Integer

SaveSetting "BibleChoir", "LatestVal", "Version_Release", Version_Release

SaveSetting "BibleChoir", "LatestVal", "IMGFolder", frmBible.lblIMGFolder.Caption
'SaveSetting "BibleChoir", "LatestVal", "Bright", frmPicture.sldBright
SaveSetting "BibleChoir", "LatestVal", "EachPage", frmBible.chkEachPage


End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to do more than just add the `PtrSafe` declaration. Some of your `Long` data types also need to be converted to `LongPtr`.

```
#If VBA7 Then

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
            ByVal lParam As String) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32" _
            (lpbi As BrowseInfo) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32" _
            (ByVal pidList As LongPtr, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcat Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrcatA" _
            (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As String) As Long

#Else

    Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
            ByVal lParam As String) As Long
    Public Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32" _
            (lpbi As BrowseInfo) As Long
    Public Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32" _
            (ByVal pidList As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long
    Public Declare Function lstrcat Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrcatA" _
            (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As String) As Long

#End If
```

> From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ptrsafe-keyword):
>
> > ***Note*** Declare statements with the **PtrSafe** keyword is the recommended syntax. Declare statements that include **PtrSafe** work correctly in the VBA7 development environment on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms only after all data types in the **Declare** statement (parameters and return values) that need to store 64-bit quantities are updated to use [LongLong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longlong-data-type) for 64-bit integrals or [LongPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longptr-data-type) for pointers and handles. To ensure backwards compatibility with VBA version 6 and earlier use the following construct:
> >
> > ```
> > #If VBA7 Then 
> >     Declare PtrSafe Sub... 
> > #Else 
> >     Declare Sub... 
> > #EndIf
> > ```
> >
> > *When running in 64-bit versions of Office **Declare** statements must include the **PtrSafe** keyword. The **PtrSafe** keyword asserts that a **Declare** statement is safe to run in 64-bit development environments. Adding the **PtrSafe** keyword to a **Declare** statement only signifies the Declare statement explicitly targets 64-bits, all data types within the statement that need to store 64-bits (including return values and parameters) must still be modified to hold 64-bit quantities using either [LongLong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longlong-data-type) for 64-bit integrals or [LongPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longptr-data-type) for pointers and handles.*